# Why I get Realm empty when I Parse a large JSON using CreartOrUpdate?

Tags: android, json, database, realm

I tried a lot of time and I got the realm empty no data the problem is there's any error, in the end I had nothing, I debug the project I find size =1 but all the data =null, my class models are corrects I check it, why It does this ?

```
 private class ImportAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        private ImportAsyncTask(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
        }


        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Realm r = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());

            r.beginTransaction();
            r.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(ApplicationBean.class, jsonObject);
            r.commitTransaction();
            int sum=r.allObjects(ApplicationBean.class).size();
            return sum;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            RealmResults<ApplicationBean> im = realm.where(ApplicationBean.class).findAll();

            for( ApplicationBean a: im )
            {
             Log.e("<<<<<>>>>"+a.getApplication().getParameters().getTitle(),"démarrage de PostExecute");
            }

        }

        }
    }
```

part of my json is :

```
{
application: {
parameters: {},
cart: {},
home_swipe: {},
sections: [],
tabs: [],
tablet_home_grid: {},
phone_home_grid: {},
attributes: [ ],
wine_maps: [ ],
agenda_groups: [ ]
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more what your problem is? I do not quite get what your issue is

Comment: I clean the project and re-build it works now, thank's dude